# Save data in an array and re use this array in another class, using @DataProvider, how can we make this possible?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have created different accounts, all accounts have unique a/c id.
AccCreation.java creates the accounts and AccountDeletion.java deletes these created test accounts.
What I want:

1. I am able to print the unique a/c id
2. I want to save these unique a/c ids in an array
3. AccountDeletion.java, will run same code , till the length of this array.

I am using java to write my scripts on ubuntu. I am doing this cause I want to verify that user is able to create many accounts and admin can approve/delete these accounts.

Comment: Do AccCreation.java also contains tests? or just methods?

Comment: Yes, AccCreation.java, also contains tests that create accounts. We go to each account and capture unique a/c id. I want to save these a/c id and use them in accdeletion.java.